# HIVE: set variable from value of HDFS file

Tags: hive, hdfs, hue

I have a file in HDFS(lets say /user/rc/text.csv) with a one line value in it "1234".

In Hive, is there a way to SET a variable with the value in text.csv?
ie.

```
SET var1 = <read value from HDFS file>;
SELECT ${hiveconf:var1};
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to read a file from hdfs directly into hive environment. What you can do is create a table pointing to that file directory. So that there will be always one record and one column in that table.

Now, you can reuse this table any time at your will rather than setting a variable in hive.